# What does this command do in R?

Tags: r, csv

I'm using the SVA packages in R, dat is a csv file containing genes in rows and samples in columns. The file SIF.csv contains only 3 columns, array, sample and batch.

http://www.filedropper.com/samplesmall

http://www.filedropper.com/sifsmall

I followed the SVA manual, though I don't understand what does
   modcombat do here. I understand it turns the data table into a
   matrix, what why do we write **~1** in bracket ?? What does it mean?

Also, it generates an error, I think it means that the number of rows
isn't matching, is there a way to fix that?

```
Library(sva)

dat = read.csv("Combat_matrix_input.csv");
sif = read.csv("sif.csv");

modcombat = model.matrix(~1, data=dat)


newdata = ComBat(dat=dat, batch=sif$Batch, par.prior = TRUE, mod = modcombat)
Found 6 batches
Error in cbind(batchmod, mod) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

Comment: `modcombat` isn't a command, it's just a variable name. You could replace it with `x` or `madkitty_variable` and nothing significant would change. The command is `model.matrix`, and the `~1` is a formula. You should look at `?formula` to get the meaning (or read any introduction to building models in R). `~1` typically refers to a model with only an intercept term, no covariates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please kindly post your csv file by uploading on some cloud drive. "~" commands generally means approximately equal for more details of the operator see: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Also, for the model.matrix parameters refer to the manual that will help you understand the function, see: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.matrix.html

Edit: After looking at your both the files, I can see that the number of columns is different in each of the file and you might have understood that by now. Following document enlists the detailed steps, see: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/sva/inst/doc/sva.pdf. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as per your recommendation, I uploaded a sample file and sif file similar to what I use

Comment: Hi PseudoAJ, I understood that numbers weren't matching.. I followed the manual and tutorial from day 1. Though when I look at the file, I see the same number of columns in both.. Could you point me out where do you see a different number of columns? :)